# Change URL with other url Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, string, codeigniter

I have a string like

```
 $str="<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>Test url
       <a href='https://www.twitter.com'>Twitter</a>Sample content
       <a href='example.com'>Example</a>.....
        ...................................";
```

I want to replace the urls in the hyperlink like as follows,

```
   $result="<a href='http://my_url.com/https://www.google.com'>Google</a>Test url
            <a href='http://my_url.com/https://www.twitter.com'>Twitter</a>Sample content
            <a href='http://my_url.com/example.com'>Example</a>
            ..................................................
             ...............................";
```

I mean,Every url will be a segment of my web url.Is possible with a preg_replace(),Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `str_replace` like

```
$arr1 = array('https://www.google.com','https://www.twitter.com','example.com');
$arr2 = array('http://my_url.com/https://www.google.com','http://my_url.com/https://www.twitter.com','http://my_url.com/example.com');
$str="<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>Test url
      <a href='https://www.twitter.com'>Twitter</a>Sample content
      <a href='example.com'>Example</a>";

$newStr = str_replace($arr1 , $arr2 , $str);
echo $newStr;
```

Acc to comment if the urls are dynamic then those arrays will be like

```
$arr1 = array($url1,$url2,$url3);
$arr2 = array('http://my_url.com/'.$url1,'http://my_url.com/'.$url2,'http://my_url.com/'.$url3);
```

Or simply give a try with

```
$newStr = str_replace("href='" , "href='http://my_url.com/" , $str);
```

Comment: The url is dynamically created,I dont know what they are.That is only an example

Comment: Consider my edit once.You just need to create array with that dynamic urls

Comment: But i dont know how to take all urls's to $arr1.because that string contail lot of url's

Comment: Once see the last solution